# How to obtain sql query to find missing bill no sequence and it's count?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in sql table with column name billno

```
billno
1
2
3
7
8
9
10
11
17
19
20
21
22
23
```

How to obtain the sql query for

> sql server 2012 or higher version,

for following result with, missing bill start no, end no and total missing bill count, Which must be between billno 1 to 17 ?

```
Start  End   Count
4      6     3
12     16    5
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I think the first count should be 3 not 2.  And why isn't 18 included?

Comment: Yes, first count is edited to 3, and 18 is not included because that is not in the range of 1 to 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the missing values using `lead()`:

```
select billno + 1, next_billno - 1, 
       (next_billno - billno - 1) as cnt
from (select t.*, 
             lead(billno) over (order by billno) as next_billno
      from t
     ) t
where next_billno <> billno + 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea47e1db9bf9bb916cc81b794de640ec) is a db<>fiddle.